# How do i get a list of users friends who do not like a facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm writing an app to send an app request to the logged in user's friends who don't like a page.

What I'm doing in my code is getting the list of the users friends and then getting a list of people who like the page using FQL.

Is there a way in FQL that I can get the list of people who do not like the page? the NOT IN operator is not working in facebook queries.

Comment: Can you show the queries you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to get them in single query.

What you are doing is correct.